# line delimiters printing empty spaces between lines

Tags: java

I have the following java code inside a JSP:

```
  // the array storing each line to print
  List<String> lineList = new ArrayList<String>();

  // get the required fields and values
        
        String descriptionString = StringUtils.rightPad(
          ((IStringField) resource.getField("BP-PerOp:Descrição do Evento")).getValue().replaceAll("\r?\n|\r", " "), 500, " ");
          
        String internalIdString = ((IStringField) resource.getField("BP-PerOp:ID Interna do Evento")).getValue() == null ? StringUtils.rightPad("", 500, " ") :
                                   StringUtils.rightPad(((IStringField) resource.getField("BP-PerOp:ID Interna do Evento")).getValue().replaceAll("\r?\n|\r", " "), 500, " ");

lineList.add(descriptionString + internalIdString);

  // write the file
  Writer fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filename), "UTF-8"));
  
  try {
    for (String line : lineList) {
      if(!line.equals(null) && !line.equals("")){       
          fileWriter.write(line);
          fileWriter.write(System.lineSeparator());
      }    
    }
    System.out.println("Lista do arquivo percorrida com sucesso!");     
  } catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println("Erro ao tentar ler lista do arquivo");
      
    response.setStatus(500);
    response.getWriter().write("{\"erro\": \"Houve um erro na geração do arquivo.\"}");
    response.getWriter().close();
  } finally {
    fileWriter.close();
  }
```

When I open the file on notepad++, the file is working as each line is separeted correctly:
[image: correct]

And at the end of each line I see the line delimiters CRLF

But when I open the file on windows notepad, I see a line with spaces between each line like this:
[image]

Does anyone know what is wrong with my code?

PS: this part of the code:

```
((IStringField) resource.getField("BP-PerOp:XXXXXXXX")).getValue()
```

returns an string like "Aporte de rentabilidade de portabilidade entre planos." as you see on the pic #2, we need this string to be 500 characters long that's why I used the rightPad function to complete with empty spaces.

Comment: Could you upload the full file content on some website or maybe post it here? Maybe show a full screenshot of notepad++ to the right end of the first line. Might just be a `\r\n` vs `\n` issue. Hard to guess.

Comment: FWIW, this is not going to work: `!line.equals(null)` if line is null. Because you can't call `equals` on null.  Use `line == null`.

Comment: @Zabuzard here's the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T2cXUTVocHud6Si6Y9RtW4pKGC_ggs7w/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @user15187356 thanks for the tip, btw do you mean `line != null` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, `line != null`

Comment: I can reproduce it. It is just that your notepad wraps the very long line and Notepad++ does not. You can change the settings and then have whatever behavior you want. Not really a problem with any Java code, more with how to use those text editors correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those space characters are actually in the file.  The lines are over a thousand characters long (which I determined just by opening the file in Notepad++, scrolling horizontally to the end of the first line, and reading the position info off the status line in Notepad++).

Your notepad is configured to wrap lines, so that the spaces look like a blank line..

Your notepad++ is not configured to wrap lines.

Your lines are over 1000 characters long since you construct them from two strings that you each pad to 500 characters.

Comment: Actually, Notepad is not configured to wrap lines. You can see the horizontal scroll bar in Noteapd, which is not there when line wrapping is enabled. It's a bug in Notepad, that when lines are too long, it wraps them even though you ask it not to.